# How to properly send POST data?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to improve my login system to run without refreshing the page. I'm quite new to ajax. The tutorials I've found all use GET. I don't want to use get.
Here is my code:

login.php (I removed the CSS code from this)

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "login/loginJS.js"></script>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div class="rounded">
        <form method='POST' action = "processLogin.php">
            Username:<input type="text" class = "input1" name = "username"/><br>
            Password:<input type="password" class = "input1" name = "password"/><br>
            Remember Me?<input type="checkbox" name = "remember"/?><br>
            <?php
            session_start();
            echo'<p id="errorField" class="error"></p>';
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value = "Login" class = "button" onclick='process()'/>
            <b><p>New User? <a href="register.php">Register</a></p></b>
        </form>
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

loginJS.js

```
xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
{
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }

    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("The XML Http Request Failed");
    }else{
        return xmlHttp;
    }
}

function process(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0){
        login = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("loginField").value);
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "login/processLogin.php",true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
        xmlHttp.send();
    }else{
        setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("errorField").innerHTML = message;
        }
    }
}
```

processLogin.php

```
      <?php
    session_start();
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
    echo "<response>";
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if ($username == '' or $password == '')
        {
            echo 'The username/password fields may not be blank.';
        }else{
            echo 'This is a test';
        }
    echo "</response>";
?>
```

So my question is, what should I do to take the variables inside the input text and password field, to put as a post variable, then to send it with the javascript. I just need to send the username and password fields. 
To see the website,
http://rukiryo.bugs3.com
  That is what the website looks like. The login button works when I use my page-refresh method, but I can't figure out the last steps to make it work for non-refresh.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Pass the parameters as a string in xmlHttp.send(). You need to encode the values and present them in param=encoded_value&param2=encoded_value2 format. http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2007/07/19/passing-post-parameters-with-ajax/

Comment: Aren't you using jQuery?

Comment: You should be checking to see if the browser supports the native XHR object. Unless you need to support < IE6 then instead use `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: If you're quite new to ajax, I would suggest you use jQuery first and once you're more comfortable write it in pure js.

Answer (score 3):

Well in the above code you don't seem to be sending the login parameters with the AJAX Request. Also you forgot to explicitly set to Content-type header, which is necessary when doing POST requests.

```
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "login/processLogin.php",true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send();  // <--This is your problem
```

Your posting a blank send with no parameters

Here's how you add parameters

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
xmlhttp.send("username=carl&password=XYZ");
```

Obviously you will have to url encode these parameters so use this (so that things like +,* etc. don't show up in the  URL and ruin your life)

```
var params= "username="+encodeURIComponent("carl")+"&password="+encodeURIComponent("XYZ");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Oh and on the PHP side you should run [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to get back your strings

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here goes the long winded, plain ol' vanilla JavaScript way of doing it. I'm going to assume that you need support for < IE6 so first thing would be to do a check for which xhr object the browser supports.

```
function createXHR() {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== "undefined") {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0"];

        for (var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                var xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                return xhr;
            } catch (e) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Next thing is to attach the onsubmit event handler to the form. Here is where jQuery is great with dealing with non DOM compliant browsers. Trying not to be to verbose, here is a short way to account for this.

```
var form = document.form[0];

function addEventListener(el, evt, fn) {
    if (typeof addEventListener === "function") {
        el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    } else {
        e.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
```

Then add onclick event handler and pass in the function you want called on the submit:

```
addEventListener(form, 'click', process);
```

Before I dive into the process function, I would create a function that serializes the form fields. Here is one that I use:

```
function serialize(form) {
var parts = [],
    field = null,
    i,
    len,
    j,
    optLen,
    option,
    optValue;

for (i = 0, len = form.elements.length; i < len, i++) {
    field = form.elements[i];

    switch(field.type) {
        case "select-one":
        case "select-multiple":

            if (field.name.length) {
                for ( j = 0, optLen = field.options.length; j < optLen; j++) {
                    option = field.options[j];
                    if (option.selected) {
                        optValue = "";
                        if (option.hasAttribute) { //DOM compliant browsers
                            optValue = (option.hasAttribute("value") ? 
                                option.value : option.text);
                        } else {
                            optValue = (option.attributes["value"].specified ? 
                                option.value : option.text);
                        }
                        parts.push(encodeURIComponent(field.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(optValue));
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case undefined: //fieldset 
        case "file":    //file input
        case "submit":  //submit button
        case "reset":   //reset button
        case "button":  //custon button
            break;

        case "radio":    //radio button
        case "checkbox": //checkbox
            if (!field.name) {
                break;
            }
            /* falls through */

        default: 
            //don't include form fields without names
            if (field.name.length) {
                parts.push(encodeURIComponent(field.name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(field.value));
            }
    }
}
return parts.join("&");
}
```

Now within the process function we could do something like this:

```
process(e) {
    var data = serialize(form);
    handlePostRequest(data, handleResponse); //initiates ajax request and passes in callback function
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents default behavior of loading new page with results;
}
```

Ok..whew. We are almost done.

Here is the function that handles the ajax call:

```
function handlePostRequest(data, callback) {
    var xhr = createXHR(),
        data = data;

    xhr.open("POST", "login/processLogin.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if ((status >= 200 && status < 300)) || status === 304) {
                 callback(xhr.responseXML);
            } else {
              alert("An error occurred");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Then the last and final piece would be the callback function.

```
function handleResponse(response) {
    var xmlResponse = response,
        xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement,
        message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

    document.getElementById("errorField").innerHTML = message;
}
```

It might seem overwhelming but it is a pattern that is followed for most post request. In all honesty this is where the beauty of jQuery would come in. But it is always a good educational experience to see how it is done with plain JavaScript. I'm sure I probably missed something, so if any questions let me know! I'm going to sleep!

Answer (score -1):

i recommend that you use jQuery,its has lesser code and is easier 
here is a link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you use jQuery, instead of creating XmlHttpRequest objects manually, as it manages to solve some compatibility issues between browsers, and makes the whole thing way simpler.

With jQuery, you will be able to do the request using something like this:

```
$.post({
    url: "http://example.com/....",
    data: {"username": "your_user_here", "password": "your_password_here"},
    success: function(){
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
```

Anyways, there are a lot of options there and the topic is quite long to fit in a SO answer, so I recommend you have a look at the jQuery Ajax documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

and in particular this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

### Update

<del>The only problem here is that php usually expects to receive data in form-encoded format, but with this your script will get json data.. (so, expect *not* to be able to use `$_POST`) with other languages (python, nodejs, ..) this is not a problem; I don't know how to handle this with php but I'm pretty confident there's a way to do that. Of course, you can fallback on sending form-encoded data, but JSON is the de-facto standard for these things nowdays..</del>

Sorry, I was remembering incorrectly, but the default behavior of jQuery is to urlencode the POST data, so you'll be fine with reading values from `$_POST`, when doing requests with the code above..

Comment: I'm going AFK, hope this helps, if you have any question, feel free to comment, I'll reply tomorrow..

Comment: Actually, jQuery.ajax converts the `data` setting to a properly encoded querystring http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings PHP wouldn't have an issue with processing it.

Comment: anyways, may I know the reason for the downvotes? I explained to him how to do that the right & simple way, since: 1. the question is tagged jQuery; 2. it doens't make any sense of directly using xmlHttp objects (that, a part from requiring much more code, will probably only work on a few browsers) and reinvent methods to urlencode forms: everything it's already there in jQuery!

Comment: your answer still contains false information about how jQuery encodes parameters

Comment: Seriously? I'm the only one who pointed him in the right direction (aka. "don't rewrite unneeded wheels"), and the only thing you notice is that I was remembering incorrectly the default behavior of a function?